# Put ASP.NET controls inline using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to put ASP.NET controls inline using bootstrap?

I have this 3 controls, but I am unable to put them inline. I have tried out few bootstrap classes, but non of them helped me out.

```
<div class="control-group checkbox">
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkConfirmed" Enabled="false" />
     <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkConfirmed" meta:resourcekey="settlementFrequencyConfirmed"></asp:Label>
     <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" CssClass="validator" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSettlementFrequencyConfirmed" OnServerValidate="OnServerValidateConfirmedCheckbox" meta:resourcekey="rfvSettlementFrequencyConfirmed" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
```

Currently I am getting validation message under check-box and label.

[image]

Does somebody knows what is the best class to use in this scenario instead of 'control-group checkbox'?

This is HTML output:

```
<div class="control-group checkbox">
     <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_chkConfirmed" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$main$main$settlementFrequency$chkConfirmed" disabled="disabled"></span>
     <label for="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_chkConfirmed">Settlement frequency confirmed</label>
     <span id="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_ctl14" class="validator" style="display: inline;">Confirm settlement frequency.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `form-control` and `input-group` classes? I think inline is default, once you have those tags. See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: The first thing to do is to look at the HTML you get getting rather than the ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming below is how your markup is output, drop the `control-group` and `checkbox` classes and write out the `CustomValidator` as an inline element:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkConfirmed" />
  <label for="chkConfirmed">    
    Checkbox label
  </label>
  <span class="validator">
    alert
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edited with your actual output:**
I've still dropped the checkbox class because you're not using it in a way that matches the Bootstrap pattern.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="control-group">
  <span class="aspNetDisabled">
    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_chkConfirmed" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$main$main$settlementFrequency$chkConfirmed" disabled="disabled">
  </span>
  <label for="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_chkConfirmed">
    Settlement frequency confirmed
  </label>
  <span id="ctl00_ctl00_main_main_settlementFrequency_ctl14" class="validator alert alert-danger">
    Confirm settlement frequency.
  </span>
</div>
```